# Home network, setup for multi-AP with LAN and NAS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, nas

I'm looking to build a proper home network. We have Fiber, so have a single RJ45 cable coming into the house from the Fiber box that plugs into the ISP supplied router. On the router, authentication details for the network are set.

I'm looking to build it out with a 16 port switch, two APs, and a NAS however I am a little confused at the correct setup. If the RJ46 cable comes straight in from the Fiber box into a switch, it will not be authenticated so every device connected to the switch will have to act as its own modem.

However, I can't seem to find a device solely for the purpose of authenticating with the ISP before forwarding traffic to a switch to APs/wired devices.

What is the correct setup (hardware wise)?

Comment: Plug your switch into the isp supplied router?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem like a massively elegant solution. Is this really the best way to do it?

Comment: "I can't seem to find a device solely for the purpose of authenticating with the ISP before forwarding traffic" -- you have one already, the ISP supplied router.